# Why are Tantras used in fierce ways? To whom they are unaffected?

Tags: scripture, culture, tantra

I have read rickross answers which are stated from tantras and angmas  but almost i found nothing scarey in what he writed so how they are used in such a fierce manner?

Is there are some type secures that tantras can't affect or are unaffected to wchich kind of people do tantras state something like this or from somewhere else mention this.? How can one avoid such attacks?

I believe that one who is devoted to his/her god/goddess or guru are unaffected by tantra atracks.  Do scriptures tantra and other scriptures support my view?

Comment: You are right that i hv written a few answers citing the Tantras.. I will try to see if i can answer this as well.. I have not read anything "fierce" in Tantras so far..they are a ocean of knowledge just like the Vedas are.. now as regards Abhichara karma (or subduing/harming others),, then that's part of Tantrik Shatakarmas..But that's not unique to the Tantras ..even the Vedas have them ..Atharva Veda have them, plus i am finding many such Mantras for hurting enemies in Yajurveda as well..

Comment: any power can be used in a good or a bad way. tantra dont recomend to hAarm anyone but in some emergency siutations there can be something against the enemies. if you have good ishta bala (power of your upasana) then difficult get affected by it

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Yes. Even Atharvaveda has mantras that can be misused like some Tantras.

Comment: @The destroyer what is the reason that only tantras are used to harm people? when other scriptures too have these type things.

Comment: Tantras are not only used for harming others... It's there in Vedas too..It's called Abhicharika.. People say so because they have very less knowledge about scriptures.. Hindu Karmas can be divided into 6 groups- they are called the Shatkarmas.. Even the Devi Bhagvatam has the details..@Fiercelord

Comment: Can you explain in detail about it shatkarmas and why tantras means sometimes it looks like scorcery like preparations etc i have very less knowledge of tantras so....

Comment: *what is the reason that only tantras are used to harm people?* This is just a popular and nonsensical view, there's nothing like that. People are harmed in a variety of ways, including by just bare hands and weapons. Śāstras even teach dhanurveda and also daṇḍanīti, but someone may even use kūṭanīti to harm others.

Comment: As for protection from abhicāras, there are various kavacams.